# Table scroll with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table like that which I fill with a data

```html
<table id="products-table"  style="overflow-y:scroll" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product (Parent Product)</th> 
            <th>Associated Sites</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        { 
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="Edit"><strong>@Model.ElementAt(i).Name</strong></a><br />
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="lesser"></span>
            </td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit Product", "Edit", "Products")<br />
                @Html.ActionLink("Associate Site", "Associate", "Products")
            </td>
         </tr>
        }
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Aand CSS like that

```css
#products-table
    {
        width: 200px;
        height: 400px;
        overflow:scroll;
    }
```

But scroll doesn't work, I want to fix the height of the table and if it exceeds, then work with scrollbar.

Comment: A very good implementation (to my opinion) is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57524791

Answer (score 93, accepted):

***Table with Fixed Header***

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="325">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="300" >
         <tr style="color:white;background-color:grey">
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div style="width:320px; height:80px; overflow:auto;">
         <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="300" >
           <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
         </table>  
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Result

[image: Demo Image]

This is working in all browser

Demo jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/6302/

Comment: this method doesn't line up the cells in `thead` with the cells in `tbody`.

Comment: The only problem in this scenario is that the thead cells will not line up over tbody cells because the width doesn't match. Here is a workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/ogcbuwjL/

Comment: This lets you overflow because you're also overriding the `display` of `tbody` from `table-row-group` to `block`. This is also why the elements do not line up as expected.

Comment: Problem is not solved. Change your thead headers lenght and you will see the titles do not match the rows below.

Comment: Hey Guys thanks for Notifying the Problem for cell alignment i have updated jsfidle to align with cells.

Comment: The real trick is you has to specify the width, not max-width

Comment: This is one of the few solutions that also works with mshta, which is the same as IE11.

Answer (score 36):

Late answer, another idea, but very short.

1. put the contents of header cells into div
2. fix the header **contents**, see CSS

```css
table  { margin-top:  20px; display: inline-block; overflow: auto; }
th div { margin-top: -20px; position: absolute; }
```

Note that it is possible to display table as inline-block due to [anonymous table objects](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/tables.html):

> "missing" [in HTML table tree structure] elements must be assumed in order for the table model to work. Any table element will automatically generate necessary anonymous table objects around itself.

```css
/* scrolltable rules */
table  { margin-top:  20px; display: inline-block; overflow: auto; }
th div { margin-top: -20px; position: absolute; }

/* design */
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background: #EEE; }
```

```html
<table style="height: 150px">
  <tr> <th><div>first</div> <th><div>second</div>
  <tr> <td>foo <td>bar
  <tr> <td>foo foo foo foo foo <td>bar
  <tr> <td>foo <td>bar
  <tr> <td>foo <td>bar bar bar
  <tr> <td>foo <td>bar
  <tr> <td>foo <td>bar
  <tr> <td>foo <td>bar
  <tr> <td>foo <td>bar
  <tr> <td>foo <td>bar
  <tr> <td>foo <td>bar
  <tr> <td>foo <td>bar
  <tr> <td>foo <td>bar
  <tr> <td>foo <td>bar
  <tr> <td>foo <td>bar
</table>
```

## As of 2016

The proper way to achieve this is [position: sticky](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/) - see the demo in the link.

Comment: I had to play with the margins a little and the alignment too. But it works perfect in different browsers.

Comment: Using position sticky, how can you also limit the scrollbar to just the table body's area? (Not showing the scrollbar in the header)

Answer (score 8):

For those wondering how to implement Garry's solution with more than one header this is it:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 235px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

thead>tr {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>column1</th>
        <th>column2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>row1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row2</td>
        <td>row2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row3</td>
        <td>row3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row4</td>
        <td>row4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
  .outer {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 300px;
  }

  .outer {
    width: 100%;
    -layout: fixed;
  }

  .outer th {
    text-align: left;
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    background-color: white;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>MYCRUD</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid col-md-11">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-12">

   
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="outer">

            <table class="table table-hover bg-light">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">ID</th>
                  <th scope="col">Marca</th>
                  <th scope="col">Editar</th>
                  <th scope="col">Eliminar</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

                
                  <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>Toyota</td>
                    <td> <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                    <td> <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                                  <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Honda </td>
                    <td> <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                    <td> <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                                  <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>Myo</td>
                    <td> <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                    <td> <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                                  <tr>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>Acer</td>
                    <td> <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                    <td> <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                                  <tr>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>HP</td>
                    <td> <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                    <td> <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                                  <tr>
                    <td>8</td>
                    <td>DELL</td>
                    <td> <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                    <td> <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                                  <tr>
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>LOGITECH</td>
                    <td> <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                    <td> <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>

        </div>

     




    </div>

  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this answer solves the problem of the OP. The answer should mention the changes in the code and the reason for the changes so that the OP can learn where they went wrong and the future visitors can learn from it too

Answer (score 4):

Works only in Chrome but it can be adapted to other modern browsers. Table falls back to common table with scroll bar in other brws.
Uses CSS3 FLEX property.

http://jsfiddle.net/4SUP8/1/

```
<table border="1px" class="flexy">
    <caption>Lista Sumnjivih vozila:</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Opis Sumnje</td>
        <td>Registarski<br>broj vozila</td>
        <td>Datum<br>Vreme</td>
        <td>Brzina<br>(km/h)</td>
        <td>Lokacija</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Akcija</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
        <td>Osumnjičen tranzit</td>
        <td>NS182TP</td>
        <td>23-03-2014 20:48:08</td>
        <td>11.3</td>
        <td>Raskrsnica kod pumpe<br></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Prikaz</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <tr>
        <td>Osumnjičen tranzit</td>
        <td>NS182TP</td>
        <td>23-03-2014 20:48:08</td>
        <td>11.3</td>
        <td>Raskrsnica kod pumpe<br></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Prikaz</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <tr>
        <td>Osumnjičen tranzit</td>
        <td>NS182TP</td>
        <td>23-03-2014 20:48:08</td>
        <td>11.3</td>
        <td>Raskrsnica kod pumpe<br></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Prikaz</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>


        <tr>
        <td>Osumnjičen tranzit</td>
        <td>NS182TP</td>
        <td>23-03-2014 20:48:08</td>
        <td>11.3</td>
        <td>Raskrsnica kod pumpe<br></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Prikaz</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Style (CSS 3):

```
caption {
    display: block;
    line-height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}

       .flexy {
            display: block;
            width: 90%;
            border: 1px solid #eee;
            max-height: 320px;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        .flexy thead {
            display: -webkit-flex;
            -webkit-flex-flow: row;
        }

        .flexy thead tr {
            padding-right: 15px;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            width: 100%;
            -webkit-align-items: stretch;
        }

        .flexy tbody {
            display: -webkit-flex;
            height: 100px;
            overflow: auto;
            -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
        }
        .flexy tbody tr{
            display: -webkit-flex;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .flexy tr td {
            width: 15%;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

This work for me

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/671664/)

```
$(function() 
{
    Fixed_Header();
});
```

---

```
function Fixed_Header()
{
    $('.User_Table thead').css({'position': 'absolute'});
    $('.User_Table tbody tr:eq("2") td').each(function(index,e){
        $('.User_Table thead tr th:eq("'+index+'")').css({'width' : $(this).outerWidth() +"px" });
    });
    var Header_Height = $('.User_Table thead').outerHeight();
    $('.User_Table thead').css({'margin-top' : "-"+Header_Height+"px"});
    $('.User_Table').css({'margin-top' : Header_Height+"px"});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div style="overflow:auto">
    <table id="table2"></table>
</div>
```

Try this code for overflow table
it will work only on div tag

Answer (score 2):

Adds a fading gradient to an overflowing HTML table element to better indicate there is more content to be scrolled.

- Table with fixed header
- Overflow scroll gradient
- Custom scrollbar

See the live example below:

```js
$("#scrolltable").html("<table id='cell'><tbody></tbody></table>");
$("#cell").append("<thead><tr><th><div>First col</div></th><th><div>Second col</div></th></tr></thead>");

for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  $("#scrolltable > table > tbody").append("<tr><td>" + "foo" + "</td><td>" + "bar" + "</td></tr>");
}
```

```css
/* Table with fixed header */

table,
thead {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

#scrolltable {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
}

#scrolltable table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#scrolltable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #EEE;
}

#scrolltable th div {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -30px;
}


/* Custom scrollbar */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/* Overflow scroll gradient */

.overflow-scroll-gradient {
  position: relative;
}

.overflow-scroll-gradient::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 25px;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.001), white);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overflow-scroll-gradient">
  <div id="scrolltable">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For whatever it's worth now: here is yet another solution:

- create two divs within a `display: inline-block`
- in the first div, put a table with only the header (header table `tabhead`)
- in the 2nd div, put a table with header and data (data table / full table `tabfull`)
- use JavaScript, use `setTimeout(() => {/*...*/})` to execute code after render / after filling the table with results from `fetch`
- measure the width of each th in the data table (using `clientWidth`)
- apply the same width to the counterpart in the header table
- set visibility of the header of the data table to hidden and set the margin top to -1 * height of data table thead pixels

With a few tweaks, this is the method to use (for brevity / simplicity, I used d3js, the same operations can be done using plain DOM):

```
setTimeout(() => { // pass one cycle
  d3.select('#tabfull')
    .style('margin-top', (-1 * d3.select('#tabscroll').select('thead').node().getBoundingClientRect().height) + 'px')
    .select('thead')
      .style('visibility', 'hidden');
  let widths=[]; // really rely on COMPUTED values
  d3.select('#tabfull').select('thead').selectAll('th')
    .each((n, i, nd) => widths.push(nd[i].clientWidth));
  d3.select('#tabhead').select('thead').selectAll('th')
    .each((n, i, nd) => d3.select(nd[i])
          .style('padding-right', 0)
          .style('padding-left', 0)
          .style('width', widths[i]+'px'));
})
```

Waiting on render cycle has the advantage of using the browser layout engine thoughout the process - for any type of header; it's not bound to special condition or cell content lengths being somehow similar. It also adjusts correctly for visible scrollbars (like on Windows)

I've put up a codepen with a full example here: https://codepen.io/sebredhh/pen/QmJvKy