# overflow is not working in this code

Tags: html, css

I have a table contains item. the items are in the `x axis`. I want to handle the overflow by adding a horizantal scrol on that table.

This is my css

```
.agent-table-wrap {
    margin:0;
    padding:2px;
    /*margin-top:5px;*/
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:4%;
    font: 14px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    color:#747474;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top:0px;
    /*background-color:#0c2a62;*/
    overflow:auto;
}
```

This is my html:

```
<div class="thirdDiv">
                 <div class="slNewClass">
                     <div class="details">
                         <span class="content">Service Level</span>
                         <span class="value" id="slSpan" runat="server">0%</span>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="agent-table-wrap">
                     <table id="agentsTable" runat="server">
                         <tr class="psdg-top" id="agentsNames">
                             <td class="title">Agent Name</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr class="psdg-middle" id="agentsStatuses">
                             <td class="title">Agent Status</td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                 </div>
             </div>
```

but the scrol becomes on all the page, **not just on the table**

check this please:

#### Before overflow:

[image]

#### After overflow:

[image]

Comment: Add a `width` or `max-width` for `overflow` to take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set a width otherwise it will adopt a width of `100%`. Also you may wish to specify `overflow-x: scroll;` to apply scrolling horizontally only.

```
.slNewClass {
   width: 15%;
}

.agent-table-wrap {
    width: 80%;
    margin:0;
    padding:2px;
    /*margin-top:5px;*/
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:4%;
    font: 14px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    color:#747474;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top:0px;
    /*background-color:#0c2a62;*/
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: This works fine. +1. will accept the answer once the system allows

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X45zV/)

```
 .thirdDiv{max-height:200px; overflow:auto}
```

Comment: your solution didn't help me. my problem not on the `thirdDiv` but in the table inside it.

Comment: this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834198/table-scroll-with-html-and-css

Comment: +1 to your efforts with me. they another guy helped me