# Horizontal scrollbar for HTML table

Tags: css

I have an HTML table with a vertical scrollbar.

**HTML:**

```
<div className="table_wrapper">
    <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody className="add-insurance_table_tbody">...</tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The UI looks like this:

[image: Current UI]

**CSS:**

```
&_tbody {
    height:calc(100vh - 350px);
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Now I want to increase the width of the table and add a horizontal scrollbar.
I modified the above CSS and increased the width of the table.

A horizontal scrollbar appeared, however no scrolling happens.

The UI now looks like this:

[image: Updated UI]

**Tried CSS:**

```
&_tbody {
    height:calc(100vh - 350px);
    overflow:auto;
    display:block;
    font-size: 12px;
    width:calc(100vh - 350px);
    overflow-x: scroll
}
```

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834198/table-scroll-with-html-and-css
and https://codepen.io/yavuzselim/pen/LNYrBd

Comment: you can share your HTML code

Comment: Can you share the exact code fiddle. It would be much helpful

Answer (score 0):

You're using `overflow-x: scroll;` If you want a vertical bar use `overflow-y: scroll;`
Use this:

```
yourTable {
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First method:**

```
overflow: scroll; // Scrollbar visible
overflow: auto;   // Scrollbar displayed when needed
```

**Second method:**

1. Make display: block of your table
2. Set overflow-x: 'auto'

   ```
   table{
       display: block;
       overflow-x: auto;
       white-space: nowrap;
   }
   ```