# Table with scrollable rows and fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/ionmang20/MVxZb/) based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11807628/3029422), but it does not seem to work for me.

I would like to be able to :

- scroll the rows
- the header to be fixed
- the headers width to be the same as the first `TD` row.

I am quite new to JavaScript, so I do not know what I am missing. The scroll part is working, but not in jsfiddle. How can I make the `TH` the same width as the `TD`?

**EDIT 1 :**

**Code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .outerDIV {
            position: relative;
            padding-top: 30px;   //height of your thead
        }
        .innerDIV {
            overflow: auto;
            max-height: 200;       //the actual scrolling container
        }
        table thead {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        table tbody {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function scrollingTableSetThWidth(tableId)
        {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableId);

            ths = table.getElementsByTagName('th');
            tds = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

            if(ths.length > 0) {
                for(i=0; i < ths.length; i++) {
                    ths[i].style.width = getCurrentComputedStyle(tds[i], 'width');
                }
            }
        }

        function getCurrentComputedStyle(element, attribute)
        {
            var attributeValue;
            if (window.getComputedStyle) 
            { // class A browsers
                var styledeclaration = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null);
                attributeValue = styledeclaration.getPropertyValue(attribute);
            } else if (element.currentStyle) { // IE
                attributeValue = element.currentStyle[vclToCamelCases(attribute)];
            }
            return attributeValue;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="outerDIV">
        <div class="innerDIV">
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <div><th>Column1</th><th>Column2</th><th>Column3</th></div>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Line1Cell1</td><td>Line1Cell2</td><td>Line1Cell3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Line2Cell1</td><td>Line2Cell2</td><td>Line2Cell3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Line3Cell1</td><td>Line3Cell2</td><td>Line3Cell3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Line4Cell1</td><td>Line4Cell2</td><td>Line4Cell3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Line5Cell1</td><td>Line5Cell2</td><td>Line5Cell3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Line6Cell1</td><td>Line6Cell2</td><td>Line6Cell3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Line7Cell1</td><td>Line7Cell2</td><td>Line7Cell3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Line8Cell1</td><td>Line8Cell2</td><td>Line8Cell3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Line9Cell1</td><td>Line9Cell2</td><td>Line9Cell3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Line10Cell1</td><td>Line10Cell2</td><td>Line10Cell3</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include here at least some of the code you have.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Yes, I just put the code.

Comment: You can do something like this, but width columns can break any time. http://jsfiddle.net/MVxZb/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a `width` to the element set in `absolute` position.

For a better looking the width should ~1 em smaller (average width of scrollbar).

[image]

If all columns spread equally in width, you may do something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/MVxZb/9/

```
.outerDIV {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.innerDIV {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 150px;
    padding-right:1.1em;
    margin-right:-1.1em;
}
table thead {
display:table;
    width:100%;
    border:solid 1px gray;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom:0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
}
```

you can use `table-layout:fixed;` to spread even width to your columns, if th and tds have no width set.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your scrolling isn't working is because you don't have any units on your .innerDiv max-height property.

For matching the width of the header with the table, you don't need javascript if you can set the width of the `<th>` and `<td>` cells via CSS.

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/MVxZb/10/

EDIT: updated link. forgot to delete the unnecessary javascript.

Comment: Thanks it works great. One more thing is there any simple way to move the scroll bar near the table body ?

Comment: There are many other ways to do this, but if we're just taking your code that you wrote and modifying it you could set a width on the outerDiv that's equal to the sum of the `<td>` widths and then set the innerDiv to be width: 100%, [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/MVxZb/14/)

Answer (score 2):

your  problem is not javascript is html
you need to separate your header and your table in 2 different containers
 not have the headers grouped under the sam container your tbody so basically you can do

```
<div style="width:200px">
 <table style="width:100%">
     <tr><th>header</th></tr>
 </table>
<div>
<div style="width:200px; height:100px; overflow:auto">
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td>value</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
<div>
```

like demostrated here

http://jsfiddle.net/MVxZb/12/

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I needed to keep the header of a table fixed I used this. I'd appreciate other solutions as well.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/56VYE/).

```
table th,
table td {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}

.fixed-header{
    position: fixed;
    background: #fff;
}
.container{
    height: 402px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```