# html table scrollable div only for tr

Tags: html, css, html-table, scrollbar

http://jsfiddle.net/AKAKAK4/hyua6zyk/2/

Please check my fiddle and let me know how can I get the scroll bar to be working only for the table contents and not the header.
Also the scrollbar appears at the very end and not immediately next to the last column, how can I make it work?

I have some commented out code in CSS through which I was hoping to achieve fixed table header:

```
#table-wrapper table thead th .uploadedDocsHdr {
position:absolute; }
```

Comment: An additional link to Daniels answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834198/table-scroll-with-html-and-css

Comment: Please update this thread, either accepting an answer or providing detail via comment or edit or even self answer why it doesnt answer your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered many times, for example:

[Table scroll with HTML and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834198/table-scroll-with-html-and-css/22801367)

[Table header to stay fixed at the top when user scrolls it out of view with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque)

[How to: Fixed Table Header with ONE table (no jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499973/how-to-fixed-table-header-no-jquery)

[HTML table with fixed headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers)

[Table with fixed header and fixed column on pure css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811653/table-with-fixed-header-and-fixed-column-on-pure-css)

Im not sure which is the best answer, but have no doubt that your exact situation has perfect answer already if you just search stackoverflow for 'fixed table header'